# I can't drop a table or create a Mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a MySQL database and this doesn't seem to work, i was able to create a review table but now i'm trying to drop that table and create a reviews table but it doesn't seem to work. Please can someone take a look at this and help me check to see what's wrong here?

```
$reviewsTable = "CREATE TABLE reviews ( 
ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
Name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
Website varchar(100) NOT NULL,
Review varchar(100) NOT NULL,
TimeOfYear varchar(50), 
DayOfYear varchar(50),
PRIMARY KEY (website)
)";

$drop = "DROP TABLE review";

mysqli_query($connect,$drop);
mysqli_query($connect,$reviewsTable);
```

Comment: What error messages are you seeing?

Comment: your tables have different names

Answer (score 1):

Just use if exists to drop the table if there is one then create your table.

Id has to be primary key because of the auto increment. all auto increments have to be primary key.  You can index website though. but i set id as primary key below this should help.

```
$reviewsTable = "
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS review; 
CREATE TABLE reviews ( 
ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
Name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
Website varchar(100) NOT NULL,
Review varchar(100) NOT NULL,
TimeOfYear varchar(50), 
DayOfYear varchar(50),
PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)";
```